# Database objects not displaying on page

Tags: python, html, database, postgresql, web-scraping

I have written a web scraper to scrape the books from a website(ToScrape.com) and display them on my webpage. I have my db created, the tables added, and can view the books information in the table in my terminal. I am using HTML and trying to display the title, a picture, a rating, and a link for each book, however all of the elements on the page just say none. I as thinking this is because of a data type issue, but I'm not sure what the actual issue is.

SCRAPER:

```
@app.route("/books")
def get_books():
    index = 0
    for page_number in range(1, 51):
        url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books_1/page-{}.html'.format(page_number)
        html_text = requests.get(url).text #uses URL of website to be scraped.
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml') #pip install lxml.
        books = soup.find_all('li', class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3') #finds all li tags with this class.
        for book in books:
            book_stock = book.find('p', class_='instock availability').text.replace(' ', '') #finds all books listed as Instock.
            if 'Instock' in book_stock:
                book_title = book.find('h3').text #gets title info and displays it as a string rather than html element.
                book_pic = book.article.div.a['href']
                book_price = book.find('p', class_='price_color').text #gets price info and displays it as a string rather than html element.
                book_page = book.article.h3.a['href'] #gets value of href in the <a> tag inside the <h3> inside the <article> tag.
                star_rating = book.find("p")
                stars = star_rating.find_all("i", class_="icon-star")
                book_rating = book.rating = len(stars)
                book = Book(book_title, book_pic, book_price, book_page, book_rating)
                db.session.add(book)
                db.session.commit()
                
                index += 1 #adds 1 to index to move the iteration to the next book.
    return render_template("books.html", books=books)
```

MODEL:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "books"
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    book_title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    book_pic = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    book_price = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    book_page = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    book_rating = db.Column(db.Integer)
    
    def __init__(self, book_title, book_pic, book_price, book_page, book_rating):
        self.book_title = book_title
        self.book_pic = book_pic
        self.book_price = book_price
        self.book_page = book_page
        self.book_rating = book_rating

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Book: ID={self.book_id} Title={self.book_title}"
```

HTML:

```
{% block body %}
{% for book in books %}
<div class="book">
  <h2>{{ book.book_title }}</h2>
  <img src="{{ book.book_pic }}" alt="{{ book.book_title }}">
  <p>{{ book.book_price }}</p>
  <a href="{{ book.book_page }}">Read more</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried drilling into the table info several different ways with my html tags to pull the information.